# Pip and python setup tools install error brings libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 dependancy in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python, dependencies, pip

```
>sudo apt install python-pip
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 librhythmbox-core9 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (= 2.14.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libyelp0 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
 shotwell : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
 yelp : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
 zenity : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I kindly ask to assist on a way I can solve this. I have tried `sudo` installing the dependecies by themselves, but I still get the same error.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the following commands for it to work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You probably just installed the OS without running `apt-get update`, so the packages' DB is probably missing a lot of info. running the update command will fix your problem.